# Play Framework - How to inherit from superclass?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a User class, which extends Model, and two classes that I want to extend the User class.

**User.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model implements RoleHolder {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

...
```

**Driver.java:**

```
public class Driver extends User {
...
```

**Customer.java:**

```
public class Customer extends User {
...
```

**Edit**
All three entities need to be directly accessed. To say it another way, I have Users, Customers, and Drivers; Customers and Drivers just happen to share all of the properties of a User. Therefore, I need to have a valid User entity as well as Customer and Driver.

I need to be able to get a list of all Users (including Customers and Drivers).

I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work using `ebean` in Play. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry but what's the problem exactly? what do you mean by you can't use the User directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the `User` table concrete, you can use the `@Inheritance` annotation. See [Play Framework 2 Ebean and InheritanceType as JOINED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872333/play-framework-2-ebean-and-inheritancetype-as-joined) for a discussion about that.

Also possible is to manually join auxiliar tables for Drivers and Customers using `@OneToOne`.

Using `@OneToOne` would also be favor composition over inheritance, which is considered a good practice.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I tried the `@Inheritance` track before finding the `@OneToOne`. I went that route, and my problems are solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This might be an use case for the MappedSuperClass annotation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html for documentation. Presumably, this is suppoerted by Ebean, although there's a lack of documentation about it.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, unfortunately, MappedSuperClass doesn't allow the User entity to exist. It's the perfect solution if I only needed to access the subclasses though!

Comment: Then have a `AbstractUser` superclass (MappedSuperClass) and `User` as well as the others inherit from it -- It's not clear to me why you would absolutely need to have `User` as such also.

Comment: The problem with the AbstractUser class as you suggest is that if I want a complete list of Users, I have to do three queries, one for Users, one for Customers and one for Drivers. In my model, a Customer IS a User, and a Driver IS a User.

Comment: I've added a new answer for that case :-)